# How to get box api web app integration folder id

Tags: box-api, box

Hi I am trying to create a Box Web app integration which is triggered from Folders.
https://box-content.readme.io/docs/box-web-application-integrations

I can't passover the Folder_ID to my app.
It seems like #file_id# is the only parameter available by default.

Anyone have any idea how I can pass over the FolderID?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you provide "linkType" property value as shared instead of direct, you will be able to select Folders which gives folderId and folderName details in the response.